# How to build blender with Outliner Branch (or any other branch)?

Tags: versions, outliner, source-code

I build blender with "Add OptiX device implementation to Cycles" (https://developer.blender.org/D5363). I get it, everything is fine!

But! But I want build blender with outliner branch

I'm doing build now:

```
 H:

 cd H:\blender-git-28\blender

 git apply D5363.diff

 make update

 make full
```

Further build in MVS19

A Question:

**How me add "outliner branch"?**

**How me update my build?**

Now I build update:

```
 H:

 cd H:\blender-git-28\blender

 git submodule update --init --recursive
 git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout master
 git submodule foreach --recursive git pull --rebase origin master

 make update

 make full
```

But its don't working on me (version blender on start screen Blender don't update)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about building blender. See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/can-we-please-reconsider-allowing-qa-regarding-blender-build-problems?r=SearchResults

Comment: Hi. As questions about building blender are off-topic, devtalk.blender.org, blenderartists or the bf-commiters mailing list will be a better place for this.

Comment: Sorry. I thought I could ask any questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to build the outliner branch you switch to that branch first.

```
git checkout soc-2019-outliner
```

Make sure that the branch is up-to-date:

```
git pull
```

Then you're ready to build.

```
make full
```

When you want to switch back to the master branch the command is:

```
git checkout master
```

Unfortunately you can't directly apply the OptiX patch to the outliner branch because of incompatible code changes that cause merge conflict.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answer :)